# Encode multiple label in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, one-hot-encoding

Given a list of list, in which each sublist is a bucket filled with letters, like:

`L=[['a','c'],['b','e'],['d']]`

I would like to encode each sublist as one row in my `DataFrame` like this:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   0   0   1
2   0   0   0   1   0
```

Let's assume the letter is just from 'a' to 'e'. I am wondering how to complete a function to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `sklearn` library:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

L = [['a', 'c'], ['b', 'e'], ['d']]

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

res = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(L),
                   columns=mlb.classes_)

print(res)

   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0  0  1
2  0  0  0  1  0
```